# variable = windows.open() act on form input change

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, controls

Trying to get control over javascript new window
Want to know when form input area filled
And want to know how to control elements in new window.
ids, buttons and so on.
Here my test example

submit.html - >

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="input" id="inp">
    <input type ="button" id="mybutton" value ="Dell"> 
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

javascript - >

```
    $('.cde').click(function(){
    var n_window = window.open("submit.html");
    $(n_window).ready(function(){
        $('#inp').focus(function(){
            $('#mybutton').val('cns');
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Only the current document can be used with jQuery's ready(), and opening a new window is not async ?

Comment: Have you tried `$(n_window.document).ready(...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the current document can be used with `ready()`, and you don't need it for event handlers in a new window. You would do that like this :

```
$(function() {
    $('.cde').on('click', function() {
        var n_window = window.open("test2.html");

        n_window.onload = function() {
            $('#inp', n_window.document).on('focus', function() {
                $('#mybutton', n_window.document).val('cns');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RdEVS/1/)

Comment: It's almost what i want. It works in fiddle but you use 'var html = '<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang="en-US"><head></head><body><form><input type="input" id="inp"><input type ="button" id="mybutton" value ="Dell"></form></body></html>';' and pass it through document.write. I want to use existing file. But this still good idea. Thanks

Comment: @alexela - Well, did you try it with an existing file? There's no way to create a file in a JSfiddle, so I had to to just write the content directly into the window to make an example.

Comment: Then the document is'nt ready, edited the answer again, works for me !

Comment: YEESSS! it starting to make sense. Now it worked!! You are genius!